# C++ needs an intermediate variable to accept iterators in <vector <vector int>>

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, iterator

The following generates error:

```
int main() {

  mat_int mat1(5, vector<int>{1,2,3});
  mat_int mat2(5, vector<int>{4,5,6});

  for (auto it1 = mat1.begin(); it1 != mat1.end() ; ++it1) {
        for (auto it11 =  *it1.begin(); it11 != *it1.end(); it11++)
            cout << *it11;
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Compiler doesn't accept the inner loop iterators;
/home/asabbah/programming/C++/vectors1.cpp:16:28: error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >’ has no member named ‘begin’

However, if I insert a temp variable:

```
vector<int> temp = *it1;
```

then:

```
for (auto it11 = temp.begin(); it11 != temp.end(); it11++);
```

everything goes fine.

Any idea why is this so?

Comment: It's an [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) problem. Try e.g. `it1->begin()` instead, or `(*it1).begin()`.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the *member access* operator `.` has a [higher priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the *dereference* operator `*`. So it tries to access the `begin()` method in `it1` (which doesn't exist), and then attempts to dereference the result.

Instead of

```
auto it11 =  *it1.begin();
```

do

```
auto it11 =  it1->begin();
```

Which does what you're intending to do in one step.

Using the temporary variable makes the compiler do the dereference first, and then tries to access the `begin` method in your temporary variable.